# netsh.exe message translations

Tags: cmd, localization, netsh

Where can I find all messages translated into different languages for [netsh.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html)?

My problem is that I run netsh.exe to handle a Wi-Fi hotspot in my application and read/parse the output to see what happened. Now the problem is, that I cannot really parse the output, because it is different in every language version of Windows.

I am looking for a site that could have all the localized messages from the netsh.exe. Is there any? Another solution would be to somehow force the messages to another language (English), but I haven’t seen a good way to do that.

Comment: Somewhat related (despite the title, as to the dependence of the output from NETSH on the Windows version, incl. natural language): *[How can I run this PowerShell script in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73669661/how-can-i-run-this-powershell-script-in-a-batch-file)*

Answer (score 0):

I went with alternative solution: .NET and [P/Invoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services)

[Solution on GitHub](https://github.com/Tviljan/WifiHotspotStatus).

Comment: This is not much more than a link-only answer. And links break, even on GitHub (there are many examples of that). Can you [summarise here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37918651/edit)? (But ************* ***without*** ************* "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)