# How can I run this PowerShell script in a batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

How can I run this PowerShell script in a batch file?

```
(netsh wlan show profiles) | Select-String "\:(.+)$" |
%{$name=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} |
%{(netsh wlan show profile name="$name" key=clear)}  |
Select-String "Key Content\W+\:(.+)$" |
%{$pass=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} |
%{[PSCustomObject]@{ PROFILE_NAME=$name;PASSWORD=$pass }} |
Format-Table -AutoSize >> "Wifi.txt"
```

I found some solutions, but I couldn't find a regular way, so I couldn't solve this problem.

I want to run all PowerShell lines in one line in a batch file, like `powershell.exe -command.....`, but I don't know how to put the sentence like this.

Comment: You know you don't need a batch file to run a PowerShell script, don't you? You may run `PowerShell /?` to learn how to properly call a PowerShell script. ;-)

Comment: Running it from poweshell is better, but the requirement might be larger and form part of an existing batch-file. What exactly are your intentions. Is the scriot saved as a `.ps1` or do you want to simply run each line from batch-file?

Comment: This is used as *an example* in [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420305/moderators-removing-individual-comments-which-do-not-fall-outside-of-known-guide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***PowerShell in One line***

---

```
netsh wlan show profiles|SLS "\:(.+)$"|%{$SSID=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_}|%{(netsh wlan show profile name="$SSID" key=clear)}|SLS "Conte.*:(.+)$"|%{$pass=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_}|%{[PSCustomObject]@{SSID=$SSID;PASSWORD=$pass}}
```

---

***With a hybrid batch file / PowerShell:***

```
<# : batch script
@rem # The previous line does nothing in Batch, but begins a multiline comment block in PowerShell. This allows a single script to be executed by both interpreters.
@echo off
Title Wifi Passwords Recovery
setlocal
cd "%~dp0"
Color 0B & echo(
Echo( Please Wait a while ... Executing the PowerShell command ...
powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -Command "Invoke-Expression $([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('%~f0'))"
If Exist WifiKeys.txt Start /MAX "" WifiKeys.txt
EndLocal
goto:eof
#>
# Here write your PowerShell commands...
netsh wlan show profiles|SLS "\:(.+)$"|%{$SSID=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_}|%{(netsh wlan show profile name="$SSID" key=clear)}|SLS "Conte.*:(.+)$"|%{$pass=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_}|%{[PSCustomObject]@{SSID=$SSID;PASSWORD=$pass}}>WifiKeys.txt
```